# Error occurred processing XML on spring application context (STS 3.5.0)

Tags: xml, spring, applicationcontext, dwr

I recently moved to 64 bit Windows 7 and download and installed STS 3.5.0 for 64 bit (Apr 18th - latest release). When I import my work space project, I am getting below error on application  context and it occurred on the `<dwr:remote javascript="AjaxService">`this  line.

Error message as : 
    Error occured processing '/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml'

my application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
       http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd"
default-dependency-check="none" default-lazy-init="false">

<aop:spring-configured />



<bean class="com.program.web.AjaxService">
    <constructor-arg ref="zyprexa"></constructor-arg>
    <dwr:remote javascript="AjaxService">
        <dwr:include method="getCityAndState"/>
        <dwr:include method="findDiagnoses"/>
        <dwr:include method="getAddrByPersonOid"/>
        <dwr:include method="getEmailsByPersonOid"/>
        <dwr:include method="getPhonesByPersonOid"/>
        <dwr:include method="getFaxesByPersonOid"/>
    </dwr:remote>
</bean>


</beans>
```

Exception stack trace:

```
complete error message as :java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
    at org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrNamespaceHandler$RemoteBeanDefinitionDecorator.decorate(DwrNamespaceHandler.java:338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.decorate(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:99)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver$ElementTrackingNamespaceHandler.decorate(DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateBeanDefinitionIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1448)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateBeanDefinitionIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ToolingFriendlyBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.processBeanDefinition(BeansConfig.java:1289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:205)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ToolingFriendlyBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:1333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.registerBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:406)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.loadBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:449)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

can any one please let me know what I am missing in here? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [Spring 4](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html#forName-java.lang.String-java.lang.ClassLoader-) and it seems [DWR is not compatible](https://directwebremoting.atlassian.net/browse/DWR-614) with it anymore. The method it's complaining about was deprecated as of Spring 3 and removed completely in Spring 4. Check you classpath and see if you can either use a DWR version where this is fixed and fall back to an earlier Spring version.

Comment: Thank you so much. I downloaded the dwr 3.0.RC3 where this issue has been fixed and now it is working.

Comment: Actually it is throwing another exception after I did eclipse build. I even download the STS 2.9.2 and I am still facing the same exception. We are using Spring 2.5 in our project.